# Angular 7 - how to make initial input value visible for JSON?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, formbuilder

I have problem with my Angular 7 project. I have

```
<form [formGroup]="myFormGroup">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input value="some text" matInput placeholder="sometext" formControlName="aName" #myName>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

and

```
<p id="first-paragraph">{{myName.value}}</p>
```

and also

```
<p id="second-paragraph">form value: {{myFormGroup.value | json}}</p>
```

The problem is, that in first-paragraph I can see the initial value of input - "some text" but in second-paragraph it does not show until I make any change in input. For example if I type manually "abcdef", that I have "abcdef" in both paragraphs. Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

When defining your form group in your component just do this:

```
this.myFormGroup = new FormGroup({
    aName: new FormControl('some text'),
});
```

That way you would leave the initialization of values to the components logic, where it belongs.

I also recommend defining a method like this:

```
get myvalue(): string { 
    return this.myFormGroup.get('aName').value;
}
```

By doing so you should be able to access your value in your template via

`<p id="first-paragraph">{{myvalue}}</p>`

Also remove the `value="some text"` from your template and you are good to go.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just use two-way binding with  `[(ngModel)]="name"` and initialize "name" from the component and use it `{{name | json}}`

`<input value="some text" matInput placeholder="sometext" formControlName="aName" [(ngModel)]="name" #myName>`

Hope it helps!